# Badge earn notification redirect to Election Page rather than on profile page

Tags: bug, notifications, top-bar, achievements-dialog

I just got below notification of earning a "Constituent" Badge for voting on the *2014 Moderator Election* election phase today.

But when I click on the notification it getting redirect to [*Election Page*](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5) rather to on my profile page as written. Is this any kind of bug ? Is anyone else face this issue too ?

[image]